# Add heading into a span - jquery solution

Tags: html, jquery, css

So I got the following span:

```
<span>Not a heading inside yet</span>
```

This is what I am targeting:

```
<span>Not a <h1>heading</h1> inside yet</span>
```

I guess it is pretty simple but I couldn't find a solution yet that fits to my task.
Since I don't have the option to change the html, a jquery solution would be needed.

Comment: Will the text you are trying to target always be 'heading'?

Comment: `$("span").html(function(i, html) { return html.replace(/heading/g, "<h1>heading</h1>"); })`

Comment: This is a good case for regex. You don't need something overly verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method, although I don't know if it is the most efficient. This relies on 'heading' always a being constant text.

```
const wrapper = $('span');
const part1 = wrapper.text().split('heading')[0];
const part2 = wrapper.text().split('heading')[1];
wrapper.html(`${part1} <h1>heading</h1> ${part2}`);
```

Grab the span element, then split it by heading text. Then rejoin the parts and wrap the heading text inside a `<h1>`.

[JSFIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/otkyec4s/)

Comment: You should split the text only once 
`const splits = wrapper.text().split('heading');`
`wrapper.html('${splits[0]} <h1>heading</h1> ${splits[1]}');`
edit: don't forget to change ' to `, i had to change so i could highlight the code